# How to create a query using the difference of two sums in seperate tables?

Tags: sql, ms-access

I'm trying to calculate the quantity left in each water container, based on the refills it gets, and how much is extracted.

At the moment I have created my tables as:

```
CONTAINERS
----------
ID     NUMBER
1      14F
2      12A
3      55Y

REFILLS
-------
ID     CONTAINERID     QUANTITY
1      14F             100
2      14F             10
3      12A             65

EXTRACTIONS
-----------
ID     CONTAINERID     QUANTITY
1      14F             20
```

So I need a query that will return each container with the amount that is left in them, i.e. in this case:

```
CONTAINERID     CURRENTQUANTITY
14F             90
12A             65
55Y             0
```

Where 90 is the result from the two refills and one extraction in that case (100+10-20).

I have managed to calculate the sum of all refills/extractions:

```
SELECT CONTAINERS.ID, SUM(REFILLS.QUANTITY) AS REFILLSQUANTITY
FROM CONTAINERS INNER JOIN REFILLS ON CONTAINERS.ID = REFILLS.CONTAINERID
GROUP BY CONTAINERS.ID;
```

And the same way for extractions, but I'm a bit stuck how to combine them and get the difference in one query. Any help would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In MS Access, use `left join` and aggregations:

```
select c.id, c.number,
       nz(refill, 0) - nz(extraction, 0) as net
from (containers as c left join
      (select containerid, sum(quantity) as refill
       from refills
       group by containerid
      ) as r
      on c.number = r.containerid
     ) left join
     (select containerid, sum(quantity) as extraction
      from extractions
      group by containerid
     ) as e
     on c.number = e.containerid;
```